# Unable to compile angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

Error :

> PS C:\toolbox\intern-page> tsc C:\toolbox\intern-page\src\app\homepage\homepage.component.ts
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:829:20 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.
>   829     const Promise: PromiseConstructor;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1486:36 - error TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   1486     const _for: typeof core.Symbol.for;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1490:43 - error TS2339: Property 'hasInstance' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   1490     const hasInstance: typeof core.Symbol.hasInstance;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1494:50 - error TS2339: Property 'isConcatSpreadable' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   1494     const isConcatSpreadable: typeof core.Symbol.isConcatSpreadable;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1502:38 - error TS2339: Property 'keyFor' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   1502     const keyFor: typeof core.Symbol.keyFor;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1506:37 - error TS2339: Property 'match' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   1506     const match: typeof core.Symbol.match;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1510:39 - error TS2339: Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   1510     const replace: typeof core.Symbol.replace;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1514:38 - error TS2339: Property 'search' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   1514     const search: typeof core.Symbol.search;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1518:39 - error TS2339: Property 'species' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   1518     const species: typeof core.Symbol.species;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1522:37 - error TS2339: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   1522     const split: typeof core.Symbol.split;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1526:43 - error TS2339: Property 'toPrimitive' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   1526     const toPrimitive: typeof core.Symbol.toPrimitive;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1530:43 - error TS2339: Property 'toStringTag' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   1530     const toStringTag: typeof core.Symbol.toStringTag;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:1534:43 - error TS2339: Property 'unscopables' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   1534     const unscopables: typeof core.Symbol.unscopables;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2305:36 - error TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   2305     const _for: typeof core.Symbol.for;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2309:43 - error TS2339: Property 'hasInstance' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   2309     const hasInstance: typeof core.Symbol.hasInstance;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2313:50 - error TS2339: Property 'isConcatSpreadable' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   2313     const isConcatSpreadable: typeof core.Symbol.isConcatSpreadable;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2321:38 - error TS2339: Property 'keyFor' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   2321     const keyFor: typeof core.Symbol.keyFor;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2325:37 - error TS2339: Property 'match' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   2325     const match: typeof core.Symbol.match;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2329:39 - error TS2339: Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   2329     const replace: typeof core.Symbol.replace;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2333:38 - error TS2339: Property 'search' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   2333     const search: typeof core.Symbol.search;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2337:39 - error TS2339: Property 'species' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   2337     const species: typeof core.Symbol.species;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2341:37 - error TS2339: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   2341     const split: typeof core.Symbol.split;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2345:43 - error TS2339: Property 'toPrimitive' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   2345     const toPrimitive: typeof core.Symbol.toPrimitive;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2349:43 - error TS2339: Property 'toStringTag' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   2349     const toStringTag: typeof core.Symbol.toStringTag;
>   node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2353:43 - error TS2339: Property 'unscopables' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
>   2353     const unscopables: typeof core.Symbol.unscopables;
>   node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.d.ts:82:59 - error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
>   82     toPromise(this: Observable, PromiseCtor: typeof Promise): Promise;
>   src/app/homepage/homepage.component.ts:9:14 - error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
>   9 export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {

package.json

```
{
  "name": "intern-page",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve]. One error at once...

Comment: Try npm install

Comment: Your angular/@types libraries are not installed properly

Comment: npm was already installed but updates it, it still gave me errors

Comment: This is not a question, it's just a big dump of all of your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Take all the files apart from the app_module, put them in a new folder. From there open cd to the new folder, and run npm install so you can start fresh. Seems like there was a problem when you created this project? You could also just do ng new ProjectName, then just move your files to that new folder. But it is not clear how you created this project.